# Check for a specific background-color in codeception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have a test I want to make, but I'm really unsure if it can be achieved or not using codeception. Just FYI, I'm a beginner using this. Here's the thing I wanna do :

- Select an element through text (example : "I love blue dogs")
- Get the background-color of this element
- Tests wether it's the color i want (let's say it's pure red #FF0000)

My HTML structure would look a bit like this :

```
<body>
    <div class="stuff">
        <div class="red-background">
            <div class="other-stuff">
                <p>I'm a lobster and I love blue dogs !</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Of course, the only place where the background is specified is on my "red-background" class, so the element I'm really targeting is the `<p>` and it doesn't really have a red background.

Is there any way to achieve that "easily" ?

The only thing I thought about was using the getCSSValue() from selenium webdriver and having a recursive function calling the parents one by one until I get the color or find the end of my html.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to execute a script that returns your color.

The code should look like this:

```
$color = $I->executeJS("return jQuery('my_css_selector').css('background-color');");
```

This will return the background color in rgb, if you need to check it by name then you can add an array to map names to rgb.